# Data Access component for .net

Tags: .net, sql-server, enterprise-library, data-access-layer

I am looking for an OSS data access block for using with .Net and Sql Server.

I've use Ent Lib in the past, but wondered if anyone could recommend anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- NHibernate.
- BLToolkit.

All you need. NHibernate for most things, BLToolkit for the more specific rare occurances.

Comment: I currently use Entity Framework and have used Linq2Sql and NHibernate in the past, but I am just looking for something for my toolbelt for those occasions where a client will not allow us to use an ORM.

Can NHibernate be used in that way?

Comment: No. Check BLToolkit. Pretty nice low level framework, fast, easy to work with. I use it when an ORM is not feasible for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I vote for BLToolkit!